# How can i get text string from selectable TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want build an app where I want to use selectable TextView. When user selects a text from TextView he will show this selectable text into other screen. But when I selected the text from TextView , I can not retrieve the selected text. I also use the method for TextView.

```
menu_search = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu_search);

menu_search.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

How can I get the selected text from Select-able textview?

Is it possible for Android?

Comment: You can make your TextView selectable by adding android:textIsSelectable="true" directly on your layout xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String str = menu_search.getText().toString;
int startIndex = menu_search.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = menu_search.getSelectionEnd();
String selectedStr = str.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to to the following:

```
int selection_start = menu_search.getSelectionStart();
int selection_end = menu_search.getSelectionEnd();
String selected = menu_search.getText().toString().subSequence(selection_start, selection_end);
```